# Package Babel error, unknown language option

Tags: babel

Today I updated my operating system to Ubuntu 14.04 and now I run into the following problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
 This is a MINIMUM WORKING EXAMPLE.
\end{document}
```

gives the error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'english' for package 'babel'. See the LaTeX
manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

I am using Texmaker and this seems to happen for all the different language options, even though Texlive is fully installed. Thank you for your help.

Regards Michael

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show what's the output of `kpsewhich english.ldf` from the terminal?

Comment: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf

Comment: OK. Can you find the version number of `babel.sty` in the log file? It's right at the top.

Comment: Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.

Comment: Hmm; I'm not sure what “update to 14.04” you did, because it's quite an old release. What's the TeX Live version?

Comment: @egreg Using fully-updated TeXlive 2017 (manually installed on Ubuntu 16.04) I also get this error message, using LuaLaTeX but without polyglossia. Language definitely installed. Of course, polyglossia runs without problem, but it seems to me that babel should also work, if I choose not to use polyglossia. Also tried passing options to babel, prior to document class, but no luck.

Comment: @RobtAll I can't reproduce.

Comment: @egreg Possibly installation-dependent, may depend on exact babel version. See my answer posted, which solved the problem for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by updating the distribution and cleaning out the auxiliary files

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that "works for me" and is not mentioned in any related discussions. I am using LuaLaTeX with TeXlive 2017, but I don't think that is essential.

My solution: Create a file named `babel-english.sty`. You may leave its contents empty. Put the file in the same folder as your main *.tex document. Discard its existing *.aux and *.synctex.gz files. Then re-compile your *.tex document.

As best as I can determine, when `babel` loads with default language `english` it looks for package `babel-english`. Even though `babel-english` is installed, it has only data files, not a *.sty file. So, `babel` cannot find it. When you make a fake `babel-english.sty` file available, then `babel` proceeds normally.

You may also create folder `(texmf-local)/text/generic/babel-english` and place the fake file there, then update your file name database (on Ubuntu, command line `mktexlsr`).

As I said, that worked for me. Seems like it is a transient, possibly installation-dependent, problem. EDIT: Interesting! Once I got this working the first time, I was able to remove the fake sty file, delete the aux and related files, and it kept working. Very mysterious. That might explain why the problem is not seen more often.