# What's wrong with language vietnam in babel package?

Tags: babel

I came back to a file from several years ago which used to compile very well back then. When I compiled it now I got plenty of errors saying that I haven't defined the language vietnam yet (package Babel error). These errors correspond to `\vn` in the file which stands for `\fontencoding{T5}\selectfont\selectlanguage{vietnam}`. Here is a MWE of my file:

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,fontsize=10pt,twoside,twocolumn,pagesize,DIV15,headsepline,titlepage,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnam,polish,english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand*\de{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{ngerman}}
\newcommand*\en{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand*\pl{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{polish}}
\newcommand*\vn{\fontencoding{T5}\selectfont\selectlanguage{vietnam}}

\newcommand{\textfsf}{\sffamily\bfseries\selectfont}
\newcommand{\textksf}{\sffamily\itshape\small\selectfont}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\description{\raggedright}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8ex plus 0.4ex minus 0.2ex}
\flushbottom

\clearscrheadings
\ihead{}
\chead{}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\pdfinfo{
/Title (xxx.pdf)
/Creator (xxx)
/Producer (xxx)
/Author (xxx)
/CreationDate (D:20100101000000)
/ModDate (D:20100101000000)
/Subject (xxx)
/Keywords (xxx)
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{\pl ZÓŁTA KROWA\\ \vn CHÀO MỪNG}
\subtitle{\pl NA ŁĄCE\\ \vn CÁC BẠN}
\author{\pl dzień\\ \vn tốt}
\date{}
\publishers{\pl Wydawcy}
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Well, this worked before... I've been trying for hours to find a solution for this and I can't find anything. I've been out of LaTeX for years and that must have been a mistake...

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I tried this solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394442/package-babel-error-unknown-language-option) with an empty `babel-vietnam.sty` file. But it works only with a simple file like the MWE above. When it comes to complex files, the error remains. I am working with MiKTeX 2.9 & TeXnicCenter. I uninstalled them and installed again. It brought nothing. All packages are updated. I downloaded `babel-vietnamese` which comes as separate package. I changed `vietnam` to `vietnamese` which on the other hand brings every time `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000]` (whatever this means). I just can't get any forward with this. Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't get the `TeX capacity excedded` that you mentioned. The document seems to work changing `vietnam` to `vietnamese`. Beware that the `scrbook` class is warning you of a few obsolete options (`DIV15`) and packages (`scrpage2`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, the `scrbook` issue is an easy thing to fix. However it does not affect the other two issues - `vietnam` nor `TeX capacity exceeded`. Btw, I am wondering why you don't get the error...

Comment: Well, the language name is definitely `vietnamese`. The `TeX capacity exceeded` error is really strange. What version are your packages (use `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` to find out)? The `TeX capacity` error shows up in the minimal example or in a larger document?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That's true with the language, however `vietnam` used to work perfectly in many documents... The given version is `2018-04-01 patch level 5` for `LaTeX2e` and `2018-03-30` for `scrbook.cls`. The error shows up in the full 100+ page document.

Comment: Then the problem isn't related to the language, but something else in your document :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using vietnamese instead of vietnam works fine (gives no errors, I have no idea if the script is correct) for me (I also removed utf8x)

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,fontsize=10pt,twoside,twocolumn,pagesize,DIV15,headsepline,titlepage,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[vietnamese,polish,english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand*\de{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{ngerman}}
\newcommand*\en{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand*\pl{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{polish}}
\newcommand*\vn{\fontencoding{T5}\selectfont\selectlanguage{vietnamese}}

\newcommand{\textfsf}{\sffamily\bfseries\selectfont}
\newcommand{\textksf}{\sffamily\itshape\small\selectfont}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\description{\raggedright}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8ex plus 0.4ex minus 0.2ex}
\flushbottom

\clearscrheadings
\ihead{}
\chead{}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\pdfinfo{
/Title (xxx.pdf)
/Creator (xxx)
/Producer (xxx)
/Author (xxx)
/CreationDate (D:20100101000000)
/ModDate (D:20100101000000)
/Subject (xxx)
/Keywords (xxx)
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{\pl ZÓŁTA KROWA\\ \vn CHÀO MỪNG}
\subtitle{\pl NA ŁĄCE\\ \vn CÁC BẠN}
\author{\pl dzień\\ \vn tốt}
\date{}
\publishers{\pl Wydawcy}
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\pl tu będzie trochę tekstu \vn vẫn có bằng tiếng Việt \\
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Comment: Believe it or not but I'm getting 23 errors compiling only the code you shared... They read: `Packacge inputenc Error:` followed by `Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence`, `Invalid UTF-8 byte 163`, `Invalid UTF-8 byte 165`, `Invalid UTF-8 byte 193` or `Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence`.

Comment: @Dominik well probably your file is not utf8 encoded.

Comment: Do you know what the difference is between `vietnam` and `vietnamese` apart of that one apparently works and the other does not. Is there any relevant difference?

Comment: You are right. That was an easy one. Stupid me... ;-) I saved it now as UTF-8 and it works. At least the code you posted. The full document still keeps producing the `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000]` thing. I'll have to troubleshoot that...

Comment: I found in older texlive a vietnam.ldf but in newer versions it is gone and the name is now vietnamese.ldf. I don't see a point to find out the difference. Stick to the new one and solve whatever problem you have. I know a few packages (fp notably) which break the save size stack, but the minimal example doesn't load them.